# Tensorflow: scalar_summary duplicate exception

Tags: tensorboard

I'm following the [tensorboard tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html#tensorboard-visualizing-learning) in order to learn how to use summaries and I keep getting the error below.
It throws the error while calling:

```
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

but the problem, seems to be here:

```
def variable_summaries(var):
  with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    tf.scalar_summary('mean', mean)
```

Any clues why is this happening?

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Duplicate tag mean
>   found in summary inputs [[Node: MergeSummary/MergeSummary =
>   MergeSummary[N=7,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](layer1/weights/summaries/ScalarSummary,
>   layer1/biases/summaries/ScalarSummary,
>   layer2/weights/summaries/ScalarSummary,
>   layer2/biases/summaries/ScalarSummary,
>   out/weights/summaries/ScalarSummary,
>   out/biases/summaries/ScalarSummary, ScalarSummary)]]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the source where I got the code. The [tensorboard link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html#tensorboard-visualizing-learning) takes us to the master version where the code is wrong:

```
def variable_summaries(var):
  """Attach a lot of summaries to a Tensor (for TensorBoard visualization)."""
  with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    tf.summary.scalar('mean', mean)
    with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
      stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(var - mean)))
    tf.summary.scalar('stddev', stddev)
    tf.summary.scalar('max', tf.reduce_max(var))
    tf.summary.scalar('min', tf.reduce_min(var))
    tf.summary.histogram('histogram', var)
```

The other versions have the following, correct, code:

```
def variable_summaries(var, name):
  """Attach a lot of summaries to a Tensor."""
  with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)
    with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
      stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(var - mean)))
    tf.scalar_summary('stddev/' + name, stddev)
    tf.scalar_summary('max/' + name, tf.reduce_max(var))
    tf.scalar_summary('min/' + name, tf.reduce_min(var))
    tf.histogram_summary(name, var)
```